# Python: Error when converting NaN values ​to 0

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm converting NaN data to 0 in Python. It seems to be translated but then when I look at the dataframe the values ​​still show as NaN how can I fix this.

After processing the data, it still returns NaN

```
df.fillna(0)
```

[After fillna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IL6j.png)

```
df.tail()
```

[After this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDstu.png)

Comment: Post your code as text in the question using the code tags - not as links to images.

Comment: Are you assigning it back? `df = df.fillna(0)`...

Comment: The output appears to be a list that contains `nan` which would not be affected by `fillna`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really should be obvious.  `fillna` does not change the dataframe in place.  It returns a new dataframe.  Do:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```